# Android - progressdialog not displaying in AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an android app that I am having trouble with.

Basically the `ProgressDialog` is not showing at all. I believe this to be a threading issue of some sort but I don't know how to fix it.

I am using `ActionBarSherlock` with some `Fragments`. I am also using the new Android `DrawerLayout` where I have my options on the drawer, which replace a fragment when clicked.

On first load of my app, I want to check the database to see if the inital data has been downloaded. If not, then I go off and begin an `AsyncTask` to download the data. This SHOULD have a  `ProgressDialog` display during this, but it doesnt.

Can someone see where I am going wrong? Thanks.

**MainScreen** - The default landing page/fragment when the app opens

```
public class MainScreen extends SherlockFragment {
    public static final String TAG = "MainScreen";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);

        ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgMainScreen);
        imgLogo.setOnClickListener(new ButtonHandler(getActivity()));

        checkDatabase();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void checkDatabase() {
        //Ensure there is data in the database
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this.getSherlockActivity());
        db.checkDatabase();
    }
...
}
```

**DBHelper.checkDatabase()** - The method that initiates the download

```
public void checkDatabase() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        //Connect to net and download data
        NetworkManager nm = new NetworkManager(activity);
        if (!nm.downloadData()) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.internetCheck, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and finally
**NetworkManager.downloadData()** - The method that kicks off the `AsyncTask`:

```
   public boolean downloadData() {
        try {
            return new HttpConnection(activity).execute().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public class HttpConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private Activity m_activity;

        protected HttpConnection(Activity activity) {
            m_activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(m_activity);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Wait ...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.show();

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String[] types = new String[]{"type1", "type2", "type3", "type4", };
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for(String type : types) {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                if(DBHelper.TYPE4_TABLE.equals(type)) {
                    InputStream is = activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dbdata);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    try {
                        sb.append(reader.readLine());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Error retriveving data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Error reading data");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    sb = fetchURLData(Constants.ALL_URL+type);
                }
                cleanDataAndStore(sb, type);
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
              progressDialog.hide();
        }
    }
```

Using the above code, all I get is a white screen as the app tries to load, and sometimes an ANR. When the download is done, the fragment loads. So it works fine except for the missing `ProgressDialog`.

PS, Notice I'm setting the `activity` in each constructor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `.get()` from `return new HttpConnection(activity).execute().get();` You are basically locking your UI thread. Once removed it should work as AsyncTasks are expected to work.

The purpose is to be Asynchronous so `boolean downloadData()` should have a return type of `void`. If you need to do something with the data then you should implement an interface "listener" and pass it to the AsyncTask.

**Example Listener:**

```
class TaskConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ConnectionResponse> {

    private final AsyncTaskListener mListener;

    /**
     *
     */
    public TaskConnect(AsyncTaskListener listener) {
        ...
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPreExecute(mId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ConnectionResponse doInBackground(Void... cData) {
        ...
        return responseData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ConnectionResponse response) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onComplete(response);
        } else {
            LOG.w("No AsyncTaskListener!", new Throwable());
        }
    }
}

public interface AsyncTaskListener {
    public abstract void onPreExecute(int id);
    public abstract void onComplete(ConnectionResponse response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not the common issue of others where they were calling get() method after execute() method. My issue was the Context I was passing to my AsyncTask method. I have a settingsActivity and I have a ReadMeActivity that calls the asynctask task. Instead of using the context in which is was being called (ReadMeActivity.this) I used the settingsActivity which prevented it from being seen. Once I switched it and passed it the context in which the activity was being called it worked.

Hope it helps someone else.